# Understanding standardization for normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Let X be normally distributed random variable with expected value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then its СDF is:
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{\frac{(t-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}}} dt
$$

So that normalize it to standard normal distribution we do this:
$$
Z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma},
$$
where Z is standard normal random variable derived from X.
This means that the CDF of Z is:
$$
F(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^z e^\frac{{t^{2}}}{2} dt
$$
As I understand the foregoing the CDF of X means that
$$
F(x) = P (X < x)
$$
and CDF of Z means that
$$
F(z) = P(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} < z)
$$
therefore
$$
F(z)=P(X < z\sigma + \mu)
$$
And if we take this CDF:
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{x\sigma + \mu} e^{\frac{(t-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}}} dt
$$
then we get the standartized normal distribution of X.

Am I not correct?

Comment: There are some negative signs missing the integrands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the typos, yes that seems to be right. You just need to keep going to make it "look right".

Let $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$. Then

\begin{align*}
P(Z<z)& = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}<z\right)\\
&=P(X<\sigma z+\mu)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\sigma z+\mu} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right\}\,dx\tag 1\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{z}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}u^2\right\}\cdot\sigma\,du\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{z}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}u^2\right\}\,du\\
&=\Phi(z)
\end{align*}
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf, and in $(1)$ I made the subsitution
$$u = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}.$$